# How can I speed up Pkg.add() in Julia?

Tags: julia

Take Cairo as an example, when I run `Pkg.add("Cairo")`, there's nothing displayed in the console.

1. Is there a way to let Pkg.add() display more information when it is working?
2. What steps does Pkg.add() carry out? Download, compile?
3. Is it possible to speed it up? I kept waiting for 15 minutes, nothing out! Maybe it's Julia's problem, or maybe it's system's problem, how can one tell?

**Edit**

```
Julia version: 0.3.9 (Installed using binary from julia-lang.org)
OS: Winsows 7 64bit.
CPU:  Core Duo 2.4GHz
RAM: 4G
Hard Disk: SSD

ping github.com passed, 0% loss.
Internet download speedtest: ~30 Mbps.
```

I don't know whether this is normal: it took me 11 seconds to get the version.

```
PS C:\Users\Nick> Measure-Command {julia --version}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 11
Milliseconds      : 257
Ticks             : 112574737
TotalDays         : 0.000130294834490741
TotalHours        : 0.00312707602777778
TotalMinutes      : 0.187624561666667
TotalSeconds      : 11.2574737
TotalMilliseconds : 11257.4737
```

And it took nearly 2 minutes to load the Gadfly package:

```
julia> @time require("Gadfly")
elapsed time: 112.131236102 seconds (442839856 bytes allocated, 0.39% gc time)
```

Does it runs faster on Linux/Mac than on Windows? It is usually not easy to build software on Windows; however, will it improve the performance if I build from source?

Julia is awesome, I really hope it works!

Comment: 15 minutes is too long. There is a download step so the first thing to check would be your internet connection (maybe try pinging github). Also, you should probably edit the question to include your Julia version and OS.

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thanks for your reminding. I've added more information.

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm on Ubuntu, so won't be much use here. Here is what I can tell you: Gadfly loads in about 5 seconds on my machine. `julia --version` runs pretty much instantaneously. Given the specs, Cairo should download and install in well under a minute. So there is definitely something funny with your install. I also know there are plenty of Windows users who are able to get Julia running just fine. Hopefully one of them will see this page and can offer some advice. If not, try posting a question to the julia-users google group. Good luck, it is a great language!

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thank you very much! I guess I should build from source when I got time.

Comment: Has this since been answered? Did you fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Colin T. Bowers, your particular case is abnormally slow and indicates something wrong with your installation. But `Pkg.add` (along with other `Pkg` operations) is known to be slow on Julia 0.4. Luckily, this issue has been fixed.

`Pkg` operations have seen a substantial increase in performance in Julia v0.5, which is being released today (September 19, 2016). You can go to the [downloads](http://julialang.org/downloads/) page to get v0.5. (It might be a few hours before they're up as of the time of this writing.)